# Warnings not being generated in VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

It seems to me that VS2017 fails to catch some fairly obvious compiler warnings which older versions do not.  This seems so fundamental to me that I'm guessing the problem *has* to be something I'm missing (e.g. some new default compiler setting, perhaps?).  Has anyone else seen this?

To test this, I create a simple console application in both 2013 and 2017.  The only change I made the to the project settings was to set the compiler warning level to 4 and to report warnings as errors.   Below is the entirety of the source

In VS2013 this fails.  In 2017, it builds just fine...

```
// TestWarning4127.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    if (true)   // *** SHOULD generate warning 4127
        std::cout << "Warning";

    return 0;
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here...?

Comment: Are optimizations coming into play here?  Not sure if that would explain the behavioral change.

Comment: @ChrisO that was my thought too, that the warnings only come out after the front end is done. Such an obvious optimization would likely happen there before the AST.

Comment: I would have to say no.  It does not build in either debug OR release in 2013.  It builds just fine in both debug and release in 2017

Comment: I actually noticed this in a much larger code base which I'm forced to build in 4 different versions of Visual Studio (2012, 2013, 2015, and 2017).  I had been working on the 2017 version for a few months and hadn't built the older versions in a while and went back to them and came across all sorts of little errors like this that I wasn't seeing in the same code with 2017.  That's what got me to write up this test in the first place.  But I'm thinking, there's no way I can be the first person to see this so I must be missing something...

Comment: Why should this be a warning? `if (true)` is idfiomatic enough

Comment: VS 2015 has the same behavior.

Comment: @SergeyA - Idiomatic or not, it was a warning in 2013 so I couldn't understand the difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When used inside an `if` or `while` conditions the trivial constants such as `1` or `true` do not generate warnings in VS 2017 as described in the [Compiler Warning (level4)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4127) official documentation. Excerpt from the official documentation:

> The controlling expression of an if statement or while loop evaluates
>   to a constant. Because of their common idiomatic usage, trivial
>   constants such as 1 or true do not trigger the warning, unless they
>   are the result of an operation in an expression.

That being said it's not a warning in VS 2013 with the default warning levels of **W3** either. Only with the elevated **W4** settings does the VS 2013 report a warning. It was removed in VS 2017 altogether.

For comparison, the GCC does not generate the warning either: 
[Live example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc24b3a1e469385e).

Comment: Thank you.  I should have found this myself.  In my defense, I tried to go to the docs (i.e. hit "F1") for 4127 only from within the IDE of VS2013 and was taken to a different link.  I should have also done same from within 2017.

I knew it had to be something like that.